# How to Pass javascript variable to Controller in MVC from View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

all I want to pass one javascript variable to Controller from MVC View from Form.
This is my own selected text variable which I want to pass to controller so that I can retrieve and save in Database.Any help will be appreciated I am sharing the code which I want

View -->I am getting selected text value which I want to pass to controller

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#stateID").change(function () {
         var state= $('#stateID :selected').text();
         getCities(state);
    });
});
```

Now I want to pass this state variable to controller from an mvc form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Registration", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="Save" style="text-align:center"  />
}
```

Now, this is my controller Code which I want to retrieve

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel Regmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Thanks @Rondles My issue is resolved now and thank you guys for ur quick resonse

Comment: use ajax to call the controller and pass your parameters

Comment: @zaki actually I don't want to go for Ajax because I have so may other controls also and through json I don't want to send ..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set up a hidden field in your form for the state (I assume state is a property on your RegisterModel?) and in your stateID.change function have it assigned the value to the hidden field for it to be passed on submit.

e.g:

Hidden field in the form can be set up with (inside your begin form code):

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StateID, new { id = hiddenStateID" })`

Then your jQuery would be (untested, this is more pseduo code to give you the idea):

```
$(document).ready(function () 
 {  
        $("#stateID").change(function (){
             var state= $('#stateID :selected').text();
             getCities(state);
             $("#hiddenStateId").val(state);
        });
 });
```

Comment: Can You please share some sample code to achieve this

Comment: Hi @Rondles thanks for your code it worked for me and my issue is resolved ...really appreciate your quick response