# How do i get a JS variable value in an HTML page onto a Model variable in the the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my HTML page i have a variable that's value needs to fill a variable in my Model class from an MVC project.

How can i accomplish this with few lines of code?

Here's what i tried:

Index.cshtml:

```
var mana = document.getElementById("ID").value;
var MyAction = '@Url.Action("MyAction", "Home")';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: MyAction,
    data: { 'myVar': mana },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#ResultsDiv').html(result);
        @{
            var inventoryObj = Model.InventoryDataList.Where(x => x.ID == Int32.Parse(Model.grabTest)).Select(x => x.DAYOFWEEK);
            var inventoryJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(inventoryObj);

          }

        var inventoryRefined = JSON.parse('"@inventoryJson"');
        var InventoryDataList = JSON.parse(htmlDecode(inventoryRefined));
        console.log(InventoryDataList);
    }

});
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(Models model, string myVar)
    {

        model.grabTest = myVar;
        //My Action Code Here
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Models.cs:

```
public string grabTest = "";
```

What am i trying to accomplish?

My LINQ requires a parameter (ID) to filter an object list.
This value comes from a JS variable... you see where i need to use ajax for this.

My thoughts were to use ajax to send the JS variable to an actionresult to store the value on a public variable in Models.cs.

Simple idea, but my execution is terrible, thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate.  See if this helps you:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22167353/2343826

Comment: okay i think i see what you mean, however, is that the only way to do it? is there not a simpler way?

Comment: See if it helps to change your ajax data prop to pass it using JSON stringify `data: JSON.stringify({ myVar: mana })`

Comment: and you might add to your ajax function: `dataType: 'json'` and `contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'` so it knows how to handle the request

Comment: @Fraze i got the same exception as i did before the changes, 'value cannot be null'

Comment: Your model is null. You have it as an argument but you should have instead `var model=new Model();` inside your Actionresult before assigning myVar. Or possibly `var model=Models.FirstOrDefault(m=>m.grabTest==myVar);` .  Also: am I seeing this right that your `grabTest` property has no getter and setter?

Comment: @LocEngineer didnt work

Comment: "Didn't work" is not exactly very detailed. What have you tried, that "didn't work"? Please tell us exactly what you try to achieve, what your Models class looks like. You cannot assign a value to a property of an uninitiated class instance and if that property does not have a `set`ter, you won't be able to assign a value to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the value of your model inside the `MyAction` method instead of declaring it as a parameter

To do this, declare a new instance of your class `Models` inside the code block and from then on, you can now assign the `myVar` parameter value to your `Models` instance

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string myVar)
{
   var myModel = new Models();
   myModel.grabTest = myVar;
   //My Action Code Here

   return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```